# Sinch C# client url parse exception

Tags: c#, sinch

I am using C# client for Sinch sms provider: [Nuget Package link](https://github.com/sinch/nuget-serversdk)

Here is my code for sending sms using Sinch:

```
using Sinch.ServerSdk;

var smsApi = SinchFactory
                    .CreateApiFactory("my_service_plan_id", "my_secret_key")
                    .CreateSmsApi();
```

I am getting errors even before sending sms. Here is stack trace:

```
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Sinch.WebApiClient.WebClientRequestInterceptor`1..ctor(String baseUri, IHttpClient httpClient, IActionFilter[] filters)
   at Sinch.WebApiClient.WebApiClientFactory.CreateClient[T](String baseUri, IActionFilter[] filters)
   at Sinch.ServerSdk.ApiFactory.CreateApiClient[T](String url)
   at Sinch.ServerSdk.ApiFactory.CreateSmsApi()
```

Comment: where are you specifying the host name? I'm not familiar with this API, but the issue seems clear enough

Comment: hostname is not specified, it should be built by sdk using my_service_plan_id, in this case I guess developers of library have not updated it, or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be right. This works in a console application:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sinch.ServerSdk;

class Program
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        sendSMS().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    private static async Task sendSMS()
    {
        var smsApi = SinchFactory
                       .CreateApiFactory("mykey", "mysecretkey")
                       .CreateSmsApi();
        var sendSmsResponse = await smsApi.Sms("<mynumber>", "Hello world, this is a text message.").Send();
    }
}
```

and the syntax for asp.net web apps is similar. Probably your `"mykey"`, or `"mysecretkey"` is incorrect.